Content Security Policy directive violation in ASP.NET application
I have an ASP.NET application that goes through Cloudfare for web security and then reaches the application.
When I load the application for the first time i.e., Home page, the javascript and css files are blocked and when I navigate to other pages and come to the Home page there js and css files are not blocked.
This does not take place if the request doesn't flow through Cloudfare.
I get this error:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive : "script-src https://www.origin/javascript/file1.js https://www.origin/javascript/file2.js 'sha256-....' 'sha256-...'. Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword , a hash or a nonce is required to enable inline execution.

I'm trying to understand what is it that Cloudfare is doing here so that the scripts are getting blocked on load and there is no problem when navigated to different pages and come back.
I do not want to add any 'unsafe-inline' keyword in coding just to bypass this issue . Is there anything that needs to be done for the js files for this?

"I'm trying to understand what is it that Cloudfare is doing here" - Cloudflare is injecting a HTTP Content-Security-Policy header into its/your HTTP responses- these headers have the effect of instructing browsers to disregard <script> elements in your HTML unless they have their Subresource Integrity set. - Cloudflare does this to protect you from XSS caused by your HTML blindly loading in a  .js file from some other website on the Internet.

...basically this is what happens today to websites made by those people in the mid-to-late-2010s when JS+Stylesheet CDNs went cargo-cult and beyond ("it makes the site faster!") - they're so incapable of critically appraising trends that they thought that absolutely nothing could ever go wrong by loading entire dependencies from a URI with a domain that was just waiting to be acquired by an adtech company.

@Dai - How do I fix the problem ? How do I make the browser trust the js files and load it ?. That too only on the first load of the website

Follow this article for instructions on how to add integrity="" hashes to your scripts: https://content-security-policy.com/hash/

@Dai - why does it fail to load only first time. Why is it that subsequent loads there are no errors?

I don't know, but I assume that might be CloudFlare choosing to enable the policy or not depending on whether or  not they've seen you before.
